# Is there a way to append a fragment to the current URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

I'm relatively new to PHP and I was wondering if it was possible to modify the current url with a *#something* on the server in PHP (Or I guess another language; JavaScript perhaps)?

Thanks for your help,

abarnybox

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I *think* what you're asking is, if you're on http://localhost/index.php, can you (from the server) redirect the user's browser to, say, http://localhost/index.php#my_anchor_here? If so, do it just like any other redirect; see [How to Make a Redirect in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with javascript

```
window.location=window.location+'#something'
```

with php

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
if ($query) {
    $url .= '#something';
}
```

Comment: 20 minutes I've been looking for an answer in PHP and that's all I was after... -.-

Thanks :)

Comment: I will, have to wait a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

Another easiest way to add #something with current URL

JS :

```
var e = "something";
     window.history.pushState(" ", "", "#" + e)
```